# Past tense of "backup"

Tags: past-tense, phrasal-verbs

Which is the past tense of *backup*?

1. backuped
2. backup-ed
3. backed up
4. backed-up

The context is the following:

> Due to the advent of cloud-based storage solutions, the data is **backed up** in different countries reducing the risk of data-loss even if a tornado **wipes-out** half of the surface of the Earth.

Comment: Side question.. I was wondering if wipes-out is *correct* too

Comment: Drop the hyphen in wipes-out, methinks.

Comment: @Mahnax How about _wipe-out_ as a noun? Hyphen, yes?

Comment: @Sarah Actually, wipeout is already a commonly accepted noun, but as [this dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wipeout) shows, both are acceptable.

Comment: @Pacerier No, `wipes-out` isn't correct.  It's being used as a verb, so it should be `wiped out` or `wipes out`.  Either would do there.  If it were a noun it would be `wipeout` (or `wipe-out`) with `wipeouts` for plural, much like `backup` and `backups`.

Comment: Related: [Back up data or back data up](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41147/back-up-data-or-back-data-up)

Comment: I'm reminded of the outtro to an Apples In Stereo song, in which an audience member is heard to shout "everything's feedbacking, can't you hear it?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Backed up* is the correct form. I never saw anyone spell it *backuped* or *backup-ed* until today. Also see the n-gram chart. [image: [n-gram chart][1].]

Comment: Btw how did you get this chart?

Comment: +1 for N-gram. (Especially if my edits are accepted ;) Actually, I'm not sure they're necessary. I'm new here.)

Comment: @Pacerier Google Ngrams http://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: Note also Mehper C. Palavuzlar's answer: "backup" is also incorrect as a verb.  "I need to back up my data" not "I need to backup my data".

Comment: yeah , phoog point , so is not backup but back up , well I do backups , and word exists http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup .
So not past tense of back up is backed up and the past tense of backup ? is backuped isn't it ?

Answer (score 8):

**Backup** is a noun when it is written adjoined. Its verb form is **back up** (note the *space* between *back* and *up*). Don't mix these two.

That said, the past tense of *back up* is *backed up*.

Answer (score 4):

The noun *a backup* is derived from the verb *to back up*.  Therefore, the past form should be *backed up*.

If it was the other way round -- if *to backup* was a verb derived from the noun *a backup* -- then *backuped* would be correct.  That's probably how you became confused.  Somehow, in your mental dictionary, *backup* / *back up* became mis-categorised as a verb derived from a noun.

Answer (score 2):

I would say *backed-up*, although from personal experience, *mistaken*, *let-down* and *screwed* are more honest.

Comment: Sry I'm not understanding your second half of the sentence..

Comment: That's how you feel when you need a backup, but don't have one (either because you didn't make it or because it somehow got corrupted).

Comment: @Pacerier - Backup is an irregular verb. I will backup (future), I am doing a backup (present), oh shit I thought I had a backup (past)

Comment: There shouldn't be a hyphen in backed-up unless it's used to modify a noun: "I wish I backed up that drive" and "I wish that the backed-up drive had failed instead of the other one."

Comment: @phoog, but I'm backed-up, or we are safe we are backed-up seems like it should have a hyphen. Ultimately backed-up migth become a word, just like e-mail

Comment: @MartinBeckett I would not use the hyphen there, but I do concede that it's a losing battle.  Note slim's "everything's feedbacking" quote in his comment to the question.  :-(